# Error Importing LightningChart to React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, lightningchart

I am trying to use Lightning Chart with React Native and I immediately ran into an error.

I used yarn to install @arction/lcjs and then at the top of my App.js wrote...

```
import { lightningChart } from '@arction/lcjs';
```

The error message I am then greeted with is...

```
Error: Requiring module "node_modules/@arction/lcjs/dist/lcjs.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: Si.atob is not a function. (In 'Si.atob(aV[t[0]][r].toString())', 'Si.atob' is undefined)
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

LightningChart JS isn't React Native compatible directly. You will need to load it inside a WebView. For React Native compatible WebView implementation you can use library like [React Native WebView](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview). Inside the WebView LightningChart JS can be used just like you would use inside a browser.

Comment: Would it be easier if I just used Electron for my app then?

Comment: It might be. I'm not sure what exactly would need to be done to run Electron app on mobile so I can't be sure if it would be easier or not.